# About Einstein's sum rule and Dirac equation

Tags: metric-tensor, conventions, fermions, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I am studying the Dirac equation and I'm having some trouble about something that I think should be trivial. I'm working in a (1+1)-dimensional Minkowski spacetime with signature $(+, -)$, i.e., $ds^2=dt^2-dx^2$. We have a two-component spinor satisfying the Dirac equation:

$$
\left(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m\right)\psi=0\,.
$$

If I explicitly compute the sum I get:

$$
\left(i\gamma^0\partial_0+i\gamma^1\partial_1-m\right)\psi=\left(i\gamma^0\partial_t+i\gamma^1\partial_x-m\right)\psi=0\,.
$$

Now, multiplying by $\gamma_0$, using the matrix $\alpha=\gamma^0\gamma^1$ and isolating the time derivative, I get:

$$
i\partial_t\psi=-i\alpha\partial_x\psi+m\gamma^0\psi\,.
$$

Nevertheless, I find for example in the following paper by L. Susskind (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.16.3031 , eqn. 1.2) that he states for the massless case that:

$$
i\dot{\psi}=i\alpha\partial_x\psi\,,
$$
which differs from my equation in a $\textit{minus}$ sign on the RHS. We are using the same signature convention, so is there any mistake in my derivation?

Comment: Could it maybe have something to do with being in two dimensions instead of four? Does your definition of $\alpha$ match Susskind's?

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with dimensionality... He doesn't specify his definition of $\alpha$, he just states $\gamma^0=\sigma^z$ and $\alpha=\sigma^x$, but he says nothing about $\gamma^1$ nor about whether $\alpha$ is equal to $\gamma^0\gamma^1$ or other possible definition. Nevertheless, in (1+1)-dim it is usual to set $\gamma^0=\sigma^z$ and $\gamma^1=i\sigma^y$, so that's why I have the doubt about the absence of a minus sign...